# PHP - Como gestionar las excepciones en esta función

Tags: php, html, php7, php5, php-5.6

tengo esta función que funciona correctamente pero el editor que uso me da una recomendación, cuando hago la llamada que la envuelva en un try-catch y me gustaría saber cual es la mejor forma de tratar esto.

```
/**
 * @param $filename
 * @return false|void
 * @throws Exception
 */
 function readCsvFileCar($filename) {

 $fileNameOriginal = $filename;
 $filename = 'temp/'.$filename;
 $countLines = 0;

 if ($handle = fopen($filename, "r")) {
     var_dump('********* START readCsvFileCar **********');
 }
 else {
     var_dump('********* ERROR READING FILE : '. $filename.' readCsvFileCar **********');
     return false;
 }

 while (($line = fgetcsv($handle,"999999",",")) !== FALSE) {

     if (($line[0] === null) || ($countLines <= 0)) {
         $countLines++;
         continue;
     }

     $data['id'] = $line[0];
     $data['name'] = $line[1];
     $data['person_id'] = $line[2];


     CsvToSQLServerClass::insertCsvLineSmsGeneralToMysql($data,$filename);

     $countLines++;
 }

 fclose($handle);
 FtpClass::moveCsvFileFromFTP($fileNameOriginal,$countLines,false);
 }
```

En el script principal la llamada la hago de esta forma

```
 //Es un csv y no ha sido procesado AÚN, lo procesamos.
 if ($pos_file_car !== false) {
     readCsvFileCar($file);
 }
```

El editor me dice que envuelva este código en un try-catch de esta forma

```
 if ($pos_file_car!== false) {
     try {
         readCsvFileCar($file);
     } catch (Exception $e) {
     }
 }
```

Comment: Pues eso es justo lo que debes hacer, pero poniendo código dentro del `catch` para que, en caso de que se genere la excepción, tu aplicación trate ese problema de manera adecuada. Es una recomendación, en caso contrario simplemente tu aplicación finalizará al generarse la excepción, probablemente de manera "fea" para el usuario que visita la página.

Comment: Te lo pide porque seguramente alguna de las instrucciones que tienes en tu código lanza una excepción en algún caso de posible error. Te esta pidiendo que cubras el error en tu código. El tema de envolverlo aquí O en otro sitio `depende de tu lógica de negocio`, no es obligatorio que lo hagas en la llamada del if, pero es como te dice el editor, una "recomendación".

Comment: @Jakala , en cuanto a tu duda, la anotación `@throws Exception` está indicando que la función puede lanzar una excepción, ya sea de manera explícita (no es el caso) o porque una de las funciones que llama puede lanzarla (en este caso se está propagando la responsabilidad de la captura). En eso se apoya el editor para generar la sugerencia. En lo demás, estoy de acuerdo.